# Low-dimensional classical r-matrices

Tags: rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, lie-algebras, quantum-groups, integrable-systems

Let $g= gl_2$. Suppose that $r \in g \otimes g$ satisfies the following properties:

(1) $r_{12} + r_{21} \in g \otimes g$ is $g$-invariant, $r_{12} = r$, $r_{21} = \tau \ r_{12}$.

(2) $[r_{12}, r_{13}] + [r_{12}, r_{23}] + [r_{13}, r_{23}] \in g \otimes g \otimes g$ is $g$-invariant.

Here the $g$-action on $g \otimes g$ and on $g \otimes g \otimes g$ is by the adjoint representation on each factor.

The element $r$ can be written as a four by four matrix. Has this $r$ (all possible $r$ which satisfies conditions (1) and (2)) been computed? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For quantum YBE there is paper: "All solutions to the constant quantum Yang-Baxter equation in two dimensions" Jarmo Hietarinta http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037596019290044M , about classical I  do not know off hand

Comment: @Alexander Chervov, thank you very much.